# Higest-resolution daily temperature products?

Tags: data, modis, landsat, satellite, mosaic-dataset

I'm looking to collect daily temperatures for a very small geographic area, and as such am in need of some high-resolution products. I have used MODIS, but the data comes with a 1km resolution.

Are there any alternatives that can achieve the resolution that LANDSAT is able to provide but with more frequency?

Comment: You may have more luck asking on the Open Data Stack Exchange, so I'd try there too: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is your area of interest in the US? You may be able to find some of these in NOAA datasets once their websites are back up.   https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datatools/records.

Comment: Basically you are correct, you have daily and nightly MODIS at 1 km resolution and fortnightly Landsat at 100m resolution. Consider also Sentinel 3 satellites, that are capable of producing thermal infrared imagery with very high precision at 1km resolution at about once every two days.